# Compare a time difference with a fixed period

Tags: c#

I want to compare a time difference with two years long.

```
        public const long TwoYears = 2 * 365 * 24 * 3600;
        string currTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        string recordTime = fileName.Split('_','-').Last();// format is 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'
        long diff = (long.Parse(currTime)) - (long.Parse(recordTime));
        if (diff < TwoYears)
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Just parse your string to get a DateTime object, then compare with your current date.

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. For example: 20051003205657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since you represent the Date as an ordered number. A more appropriate solution is:

```
String recordTime = fileName.Split('_','-').Last();// format is 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'
DateTime recordDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact( recordTime , "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

if ( recordDateTime.AddYears(2) < DateTime.Now )
{
    Console.WriteLine(fileName);
}
```

Edit: Seen from the below comments, it's better to add years and compare DateTimes.

Comment: There are some `Parse` methods to build `DateTime` that should be used instead of those string manipulations.

Comment: I'm not aware of ones that accept this type of ordering, without dashes to separate the input (and I don't want to be the guy that googles that and just pastes the result ). Can you help me out with that :)
Another option would also be to add dashes manually and then parse, but it's still ugly

Comment: [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) is able to take a custom pattern as parameter.

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Try again, I missed HH instead of hh.
Are you sure you're not missing any zeroes? Works fine for me with HH.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `-2` years to a date and compare to whatever

```
if (dateTimeVar > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2))
{
    // code...
}
```

If you date comes from a string use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) and specifying the `format` you want to convert.

Comment: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'System.DateTime'

Comment: @Love You don't need `long` type for this.

Comment: Then how to deal with strings? Convert them or not?

Comment: @Love `dateTimeVar` in this context is a `DateTime dateTimeVar`, if your date comes from a string convert it using `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: It will throw an exception whiling converting the string to DateTime object because of the format "yyyyMMddHHmmss"